# How to downgrade api in Google play?

Tags: android

I have an app in the play store, which TargetSdkVersion is 23, but now I need to downgrade it to 22.

I get an error while uploading the new Sdk in Google console developer because I cant downgrade from 23 to 22, is there any way to do that? Or something like removing the app to upload a new one with same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the app from the Play Store and upload it again with the **same name** but the **package name has to be different**.

You can **unpublish** the old app in the developer console.

If your app already has some users they will still be able to use the old app, if they bought the app (e.g. if it's not for free) they will even be able to reinstall the old app in future.

A simple downgrade is not possible.

Comment: When you say "bought the app", you mean the same even if its free? Because my app is free.

Comment: No. If your app is for free they won't be able to reinstall the app if you unpublished it.

Comment: This is extremely badly designed by Google as it also applies to the alpha releases.  This means that I can't use continuous deployment from branches in a large project freely, which has NO OTHER EFFECT than reducing the quality and testability of my software.  What's the rationale?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [selmaohneh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5779175/selmaohneh) answer. However, I would like to share the full tweak for this sad Android M permissions issue. The steps as it worked for me (Alegra Yes):

1. Unpublish the application
2. Change the name of that unpublished app in the application Store Listing tab - beware that you must be signed in as a developer with full permissions for the specific application, or the developer account owner in Google Play, to be capable to edit such things.
3. Now comes the tricky part, as written above, you need to change the package name all over the application.
4. Publish it as a new application, but with the same name.

Comment: Step 4 - Publish it as a new application, but with the same name.  Do you mean creating a completely new application, copy+paste from the old app, or is this related to republishing?